# Ошибка при работе с потоками в PyQt. Что делать?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, pyqt6

Когда я запускаю этот код у меня вылетает ошибка:

> TypeError: MainWindow.a() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>
> TypeError: MainWindow.b() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

вот код:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("NCM manager")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 320, 210)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('si.png'))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(42, 42, 40);")

    def a(self):
            reg = MainWindow(self)
            time.sleep(2)
            reg.setWindowTitle("NdfvergfvCM")

    def b(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        reg = MainWindow(self)
        time.sleep(2)
        reg.setWindowTitle("MBIM")

    t1 = Thread(target=a)
    t2 = Thread(target=b)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Comment: nurd 14, sorry, вы делаете что-то непонятное. Напишите лучше, что вы хотите сделать в вашем приложении?

Comment: мне надо что бы 2 процеса которые одновременно выполняются делали свои дела.
к примеру процес "a" менял название приложение, процес "b" менял название условно кнопки и это всё было одновременно и без каких либо телодвижений по типу нажать кнопку

Comment: Нужно создать объект окна, который указать перед a и b в target. target=window.a,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужны никакае дополнительные библиотеки.
Один из самых распространенных вариантов работы с потоками, выглядит так:

```
import sys
#import time
#from threading import Thread
from random import choice
from PyQt5.Qt import *
 

class FirstThread(QThread):
    message = pyqtSignal(str)
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.window_title_names = [
            'Какоето название окна', 
            'Другое название окна.'] 
            
    def run(self):
        while True:  
            self.message.emit(choice(self.window_title_names))  
            self.msleep(2000)
    

class SecondThread(QThread):
    message = pyqtSignal(str)
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.number = 0
        
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.number += 1
            self.message.emit(f'Button {self.number}')  
            self.msleep(2000)
 

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("NCM manager")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('im.png'))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(42, 42, 40);")
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget) 
        
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('Button')
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(142, 142, 140);")
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        
        self.t1 = FirstThread()
        self.t1.message.connect(self.a)
        self.t1.start()
        
        self.t2 = SecondThread()
        self.t2.message.connect(self.b)
        self.t2.start()

    def a(self, name):
        self.setWindowTitle(name)

    def b(self, name):
        self.pushButton.setText(name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(600, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]